# How can I subtract values of one column rows from another column row which is preceding on the basis of Year period?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, shift

I have a table which has various columns but I will only mention those which are on focus of interest.

| Year | Current Amount | Previous Amount | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 22000 | 36000 | C5 70 |
| 2022 | 26000 | 48000 | C4 68 |
| 2023 | 76440 | 34000 | C5 70 |
| 2024 | 21399 | 12000 | C4 68 |
| 2024 | 22000 | 11000 | C4 34 |
| 2024 | 26500 | 13000 | C4 23 |
| 2025 | 16000 | 34000 | C4 68 |
| 2025 | 76000 | 22000 | C4 34 |
| 2025 | 34000 | 64000 | C4 23 |

Now obviously there are way to many year values. What I want is to deduct the current amount value when year is suppose 2022 from previous amount when year is 2021, In simple words, Subtract Current amount from Previous amount where every year value for Previous amount is preceding than the default value. For instance I want the results to look like this.

| Year | Current Amount | Previous Amount | Type | Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 22000 | 36000 | C5 70 | Nan |
| 2022 | 26000 | 48000 | C4 68 | -10,000 |
| 2023 | 76440 | 34000 | C5 70 | 28,440 |
| 2024 | 21399 | 12000 | C4 68 | 35899 |
| 2024 | 22000 | 11000 | C4 34 | 35899 |
| 2024 | 26500 | 13000 | C4 23 | 35899 |
| 2025 | 16000 | 34000 | C4 68 | 90000 |
| 2025 | 76000 | 22000 | C4 34 | 90000 |
| 2025 | 34000 | 64000 | C4 23 | 90000 |

I have tried using following code but no luck so far :

```
Df['Current Amount'] - Df['Previous Amount'].where(Df['Year']==Df['Year']-1)
```

Also:

```
Df['Current Amount'] - Df['Previous Amount'].where(Df['Year']==Df['Year'].shift(-1))
```

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### duplicated data

```
# aggregate data
df2 = df.groupby('Year')[['Current Amount', 'Previous Amount']].sum()
# ensure having all intermediate years
df2 = df2.reindex(range(df2.index.min(), df2.index.max()+1))

# compute the change and merge
df.merge(df2['Current Amount'].sub(df2['Previous Amount'].shift()).rename('Change'),
         on='Year', how='left')
```

output:

```
   Year  Current Amount  Previous Amount   Type   Change
0  2021           22000            36000  C5 70      NaN
1  2022           26000            48000  C4 68 -10000.0
2  2023           76440            34000  C5 70  28440.0
3  2024           21399            12000  C4 68  35899.0
4  2024           22000            11000  C4 34  35899.0
5  2024           26500            13000  C4 23  35899.0
6  2025           16000            34000  C4 68  90000.0
7  2025           76000            22000  C4 34  90000.0
8  2025           34000            64000  C4 23  90000.0
```

##### older answer

IIUC, assuming consecutive years, use:

```
df['Change'] = df['Current Amount'].sub(df['Previous Amount'].shift())
```

Alternatively, to ensure mapping the previous year, use:

```
s = df.set_index('Year')['Previous Amount']
s.index += 1

df['Change'] = df['Current Amount'].sub(df['Year'].map(s))
```

output:

```
   Year  Current Amount  Previous Amount   Type   Change
0  2021           22000            36000  C5 70      NaN
1  2022           26000            48000  C4 68 -10000.0
2  2023           76440            34000  C5 70  28440.0
3  2024           21399            12000  C4 68 -12601.0
```

Comment: Hi there, 
Thanks for the reply.
I ran the code and it gave me an error

"InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Its because there are lot of values assigned to a single year period, thats why there are duplicate value as well.
So Is there any other fix for it.

Comment: @BirinderSingh can you be more specific? which detailed error? Also what is the exact input that you used? Can you provide the output of `df.to_dict()` in your question?

Comment: Hi @mozway 
The data is confidential so I cannot share "Dictation" data. I will try to explain the problem as best as I can. The table that I've mentioned above has more values than it has now, as I've told you before, the dataset is large.
I ran the code and it gave me above error. I believe it is because there are more than one values for a specific year period.
Such as current amount values for 2022 can be more than one and same with previous amount column. Basically I want amount summed on the basis of year and then deducted from previous period.

Comment: If hope It cleared your doubt. If not, I can share you the new DF dict.

Comment: @BirinderSingh just provide a dummy example, sufficient enough to represent the issue. The real data doesn't matter, the fact that is it illustrative and reproducible does.

Comment: Hi mozway. I am not familiar with stack overflow.
I cant fill more than 550 characters
While dictionary is some around 6000 words.
Is there any other way I can share the DF with you. the dummy one

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71925521/edit) your question to simply add 2 or 3 more rows in the existing example with duplicates, and correct the output accordingly. That should be sufficient

Comment: Done! Please check

Comment: are the values in the output correct?

Comment: Yes mozway, Sorry first time I inputted the wrong output.
Now it is correct.
Also we can do it both ways i.e.
Aggregated values on the basis of period OR
Single current - single previous on the basis of single year, cause I will input this data afterwards in power bi and there it will be automatically summed on the basis of year.

Comment: Hi mozway.
Thanks for the code and help all the way.
I was wandering what If we want to add a second grouping column there.
Like this:

df2 = df.groupby(['Year','Type'])[['Current Amount', 'Previous Amount']].sum()

What could be the the rest code for it. It is giving me the error:

can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple